# Как сделать кнопку произвольной формы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Надоела простая прямоугольная кнопка в pyqt5. Как можно сделать ее произвольной формы? Там, допустим, чтоб ее формой служила картинка.

Comment: Например, сделайте кликабельный QLabel или использовать QToolButton с autoraise=True, чтобы рамку кнопки убрать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Пример с](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/a453d8106cf7818411b06e58ab34633c536b2e72/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/clickable_image) `QToolButton`.

Картинка с прозрачным фоном **img.png**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

app = Qt.QApplication([])

button = Qt.QToolButton()
button.setIcon(Qt.QIcon('img.png'))
button.setAutoRaise(True)
button.setMinimumSize(40, 50)
button.setIconSize(button.minimumSize())

layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(Qt.QLabel('Example:'))
layout.addWidget(button)

central = Qt.QWidget()
central.setStyleSheet('background-color: green;')
central.setLayout(layout)

mw = Qt.QMainWindow()
mw.setCentralWidget(central)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведении курсора мышки проявляется рамка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ништяк, спасибо большое!